# flycheck how to silence certain errors or alternatively how to show warnings when errors are present

Tags: flycheck, fortran

```
mac osx catalina (latest)
emacs 26.3 from homebrew
flycheck
gfortran 9.3.0
```

I am trying to use flycheck to clean up and reorganize some code.  Right now I would like to see some warnings to clean them up, but there are some "errors" that flycheck is marking that I don't want to change at this point (also not sure how)

See the example screenshots below.

When an error about a gnu-extension is highlighted, flycheck will not show me where the unused variables are.  I'd like to either silence some errors, or alternatively just have flycheck show me the warnings about the unused variables.

How can I do that

Pic 1: showing the extension error but not the unused variable
[image]

Pic 2: showing the unused variable after extension use is commented out
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the default `gfortran` checker options, it seems checking stops after the first error.  You could try options that issue warnings that would otherwise be errors:

```
(setq flycheck-gfortran-language-standard "gnu")
(add-to-list 'flycheck-gfortran-warnings "pedantic")
```

Comment: thanks very much.  I had tried something similar to this, but obviously was different and didn't work.  I should also mentioned I confirmed this works on my linux setup, but haven't yet circled back to the mac setup that this was reported with, so I will have to double check that.

Comment: Also, I see that I had been setting the standard to "f2018" which obviously throws an error for gnu extensions that are not part of the language standard.  Makes sense.  Thanks very much, so perhaps in my case I actually want to leave the pedantic warnings set out, so that I don't see warnings about the gnu extensions if I am using them intentionally.  Thanks again